# How to efficiently add sparse matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, addition, sparse-matrix

I want to know how to efficiently add sparse matrices in Python.

I have a program that breaks a big task into subtasks and distributes them across several CPUs. Each subtask yields a result (a scipy sparse matrix formatted as: `lil_matrix`).

The sparse matrix dimensions are: 100000x500000 , which is quite huge, so I really need the most efficient way to sum all the resulting sparse matrices into a single sparse matrix, using some C-compiled method or something.

Comment: A simple and efficient way to add sparse matrices is to convert them to sparse triplet form, concatenate the triplets, and then convert back to sparse column format.

Comment: Is the matrix addition for lil_matrices in NumPy not good enough?

Comment: no, it sounds pretty good enough. Actually this is my question. I just don't know how lil_matrix addition works - I couldn't find an example in the scipy site. If you could please give me an example that would solve my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried timing the simplest method?

```
matrix_result = matrix_a + matrix_b
```

The documentation warns this may be slow for LIL matrices, suggesting the following may be faster:

```
matrix_result = (matrix_a.tocsr() + matrix_b.tocsr()).tolil()
```

Comment: The second one is faster to me. matrix_result = numpy.array_a + sparse_matrix_b.tocsr(), compared to matrix_result = numpy.array_a + sparse_matrix_b

Comment: A = lil_matrix((10000, 10000))
A[0, :100] = np.ones(100)
A[1, :100] = np.ones(100)
A[2, :100] = np.ones(100)
A[100:300, 200] = np.ones((200,1))
A[100:300, 201] = np.ones((200,1))
A[100:300, 202] = np.ones((200,1))
A[100:300, 203] = np.ones((200,1))

B = lil_matrix((10000, 10000))
B[100, :50] = np.ones(50)
B[101, :50] = np.ones(50)
B[102, :50] = np.ones(50)
B[100:200, 5000] = np.ones((100,1))
B[100:200, 5001] = np.ones((100,1))
B[100:200, 5002] = np.ones((100,1))

I tried this code and the first one is almost 4 times faster