# How would one go about adding a sparse matrix column to every column in another sparse matrix efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I'm trying to create a program that can add an array of values to each "column" in a sparse matrix, like so:

```
A = [[1,1,0],
     [0,0,1],
     [1,0,1]]

B = [[1],
     [0],
     [1]]

A + B = [[2,2,1],
         [0,0,1],
         [2,1,2]]
```

Represented in the coordinate format for sparse matrices it would look as follows:

```
A = [[0,0,1],
     [2,0,1],
     [0,1,1],
     [1,2,1],
     [2,2,1]]

B = [[0,0,1],
     [2,0,1]]

A + B = [[0,0,2],
         [2,0,2],
         [0,1,2],
         [2,1,1],
         [0,2,1],
         [1,2,1],
         [2,2,2]]
```

I am dealing with large matrices that must be represented in a sparse manner due to their size. I need to be able to add a column of values to each column in a matrix, but with an algorithm that deals exclusively with the sparse triplets.

I have spent all day on this, literally 10 hours straight, and I am genuinely stunned I haven't been able to find a good answer for this anywhere. Performing this operation with multiplication is simple and highly efficient, but there doesn't seem to be any time and space-efficient solution built into scipy or numpy to do this, or if there is, it will kill me when I find out. I attempted to implement a solution, but it ended up being horribly inefficient.

Essentially, my solution, which does technically work but just with terrible time efficiency, follows these steps:

1. Check for shared values on rows between A and B, add the relevant triplet values together
2. Add the unique values from A
3. Add B_row_i, x_i, B_value_i for i in the columns of the matrix, checking to see that we're not adding a verbatim value from our A triplets.

At least, I think that's what it does... I'm totally burnt out now and I started to phase out while coding. If anyone could suggest and fast solutions that would be highly appreciated!

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix 
from tqdm import tqdm

class SparseCoordinates:
    def __init__(self,coo_a,coo_b):

        self.shape = coo_a.shape

        self.coo_a_rows = coo_a.row
        self.coo_a_cols = coo_a.col
        self.coo_a_data = coo_a.data

        self.coo_b_rows = coo_b.row
        self.coo_b_cols = coo_b.col
        self.coo_b_data = coo_b.data

        self.coo_c_rows = []
        self.coo_c_cols = []
        self.coo_c_data = []

    def __check(self,a,b,c,lr,lc,lv):
        for i in range(len(lr)):
            if lr[i] == a and lc[i] == b and lv[i] == c:
                return True
        return False

    def __check_shared_rows(self):
        for i in tqdm(range(len(self.coo_a_rows))):
            for j in range(len(self.coo_b_rows)):
                if self.coo_a_rows[i] == self.coo_b_rows[j]:
                    self.coo_c_rows.append(self.coo_a_rows[i])
                    self.coo_c_cols.append(self.coo_a_cols[i])
                    self.coo_c_data.append(self.coo_a_data[i] + self.coo_b_data[j])
        
    def __add_unique_from_a(self):
        a_unique = set(self.coo_a_rows) - set(self.coo_b_rows)
        for i in tqdm(range(len(self.coo_a_rows))):
            if self.coo_a_rows[i] in a_unique:
                self.coo_c_rows.append(self.coo_a_rows[i])
                self.coo_c_cols.append(self.coo_a_cols[i])
                self.coo_c_data.append(self.coo_a_data[i])
    
    def __add_all_remaining_from_b(self):
        for i in tqdm(range(len(self.coo_b_rows))):
            for j in range(self.shape[1]):
                if not self.__check(self.coo_b_rows[i],j,self.coo_b_data[i],
                                    self.coo_a_rows,self.coo_a_cols,self.coo_a_data):
                    self.coo_c_rows.append(self.coo_b_rows[i])
                    self.coo_c_cols.append(j)
                    self.coo_c_data.append(self.coo_b_data[i])
    
    def add(self):
        self.__check_shared_rows()
        self.__add_unique_from_a()
        self.__add_all_remaining_from_b()
        return coo_matrix((self.coo_c_data,(self.coo_c_rows,self.coo_c_cols)),shape=self.shape)
```

Comment: Can you build a sparse matrix where every column is the column you are trying to add and then do something like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565685/how-to-efficiently-add-sparse-matrices-in-python] ?

Comment: I can do something like that. Initially I felt like it might be inefficient to fill a sparse matrix with the same values for the purpose of addition, but given your response and the other response this might be the best way to go. Do you think this is the most efficient way, or maybe there is an alternative to add a 1D array by each 1D slice of a 2D matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `numpy` arrays, `A+B` does the job because of `broadcasting`.  `broadcasting` is implemented at core iteration levels, taking advantage of `strides`.  `scipy.sparse` does not implement `broadcasting`.  If `B` is expanded to (3,3) matrix to match `A` addition does work

```
In [76]: A = np.array([[1,1,0],
    ...:      [0,0,1],
    ...:      [1,0,1]])
    ...: 
    ...: B = np.array([[1],
    ...:      [0],
    ...:      [1]])
In [77]: B.shape
Out[77]: (3, 1)
In [78]: A+B
Out[78]: 
array([[2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

Sparse:

```
In [79]: from scipy import sparse
In [81]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(A);N=sparse.csr_matrix(B)
```

Matrix multiplication is well developed for sparse matrices:

```
In [82]: M@N
Out[82]: 
<3x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [84]: N.T@M
Out[84]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

Matrix multiplication is used for row or column indexing, and for summing.

Define a helper:

```
In [86]: O=sparse.csr_matrix([1,1,1])
In [87]: O
Out[87]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [88]: N@O
Out[88]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Use that in the sum:

```
In [89]: M+N@O
Out[89]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [90]: _.A
Out[90]: 
array([[2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

This matrix is less sparse than `M` - fewer 0's.  That reduces the benefits of using sparse matrices.

`coo_matrix` format is used to create matrices, and to build new ones, as with `sparse.bmat`, `sparse.hstack` and `sparse.vstack`, but `csr_matrix` is used most math.  Sometimes it is possible to do custom math by iterating on 'rows' via the `intptr` array.  There have been various SO answers which do that.  Math using the `coo` attributes is generally not a good idea.

However, because `coo` duplicates are summed when converted to `csr`, I could probably set up a reasonable summation of the coo formats of `M` and `N`.

```
In [91]: Mo=M.tocoo(); No=N.tocoo()
In [95]: Oo=O.tocoo()
In [98]: rows = np.concatenate((Mo.row, Oo.row))
In [99]: cols = np.concatenate((Mo.col, Oo.col))
In [100]: data = np.concatenate((Mo.data, Oo.data))
In [101]: sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)),M.shape)
Out[101]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [102]: _.A
Out[102]: 
array([[2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Here I joined the attributes of `Mo` and `Oo`.  I could do the same with the attributes of `No`, but since I already has `Oo`, I decided it was worth the work.  I'll leave that up to you.

```
In [103]: Oo.row,Oo.col,Oo.data
Out[103]: 
(array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 1, 1]))
In [104]: No.row,No.col,No.data
Out[104]: (array([0, 2], dtype=int32), array([0, 0], dtype=int32), array([1, 1]))
```

I don't know if this `coo` approach is worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse! Initially I was hesitant to create another sparse matrix of equal dimensions, but I think given your thoughts on the matter, this is probably the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using scipy sparse arrays and numpy, you can do this quite efficiently. The actual implementation of efficient sparse operations can look a bit convoluted until you're comfortable working with the indexing of the sparse arrays, but numpy has some good tools for it.

You can do this in just a few lines, whether it's in COO, CSR or CSC format. As a quick overview, the compressed sparse matrix formats have 3 1-dimensional numpy arrays that actually store the data. The first, `m.indptr`  has an entry for every row (for CSR) or column (for CSC) plus one. `m.indptr[i]` gives the index into the other two arrays where row i begins, so `s = m.indptr[i]:m.indptr[i+1]` gives a slice of all those indices in the row. The next array, `m.indices`, gives the index for each nonzero value in the uncompressed axis- columns for CSR, rows for CSC. And `m.data`  gives the actual values at those positions. You can very often take advantage of this format to greatly simplify code and save on time. For example, if you wanted to add 1 to each nonzero value in column i:

- convert to CSC format
- find the indices of the nonzero values in column i with the indptr array
- slice into the data array with those indices, and add in place (i.e. += 1)

```
m.data[m.indptr[i]:m.indptr[i+1]] += 1
```

That's it! Now, we need to add a different value to each row or column, potentially. Doing that step in a for loop is not practical for large problems. A helpful general technique is to construct an array with the same size as the data array initially filled with zeros, and then use some combination of slicing and numpy functions like take, diff, and repeat to prepare the changes using the indptr and indices arrays, then finally update the data array once in place.

When you're adding a vector to each column of the matrix, the modifications to values depend on row index only- so if we can figure out a way to efficiently add the correct value to each row at once, we're good. If we have a CSR matrix, we know exactly how many nonzero elements are in each row, and that they'll be sorted together in the data array. Using `np.diff(m.indptr)` extremely conveniently gives the number of nonzero elements in each row, and then `m.data += np.repeat(vec, np.diff(m.indptr))` gives an array the same size as the data array, with vec[0] repeated once for every element in the first row, vec[1] repeated once for every element in the second row, and so on, and then adds the result to the data array. This requires O(nnz) time and memory only, which is optimal, and can make full use of the numpy vectorization and parallelism with no additional effort.

If you need to alter values based on indices in an uncompressed axis because of some other constraint, a slightly less efficient solution follows the exact same idea, but instead of using repeat and the indptr array, you use `np.take(vec, m.indices)`. This creates an array with element i taken from the index of vec given by m.indices[i]- in other words, it takes the element of vec that corresponds to the row/column index of each nonzero element. This involves accessing memory in a less sequential way to pull the correct value from vec, but again in practice thanks to the typically smaller size of vec compared to the data array and that the data update is sequential, it is very fast.

Edited to add: the [sparsefuncs](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.py) module in scikit-learn has some very instructive code, along with the similar [sparsefuncs_fast](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs_fast.pyx) Cython module. You might notice that the methods I presented are very similar to the code used in the row and column scaling functions- that's where I learned it from.